# Install GeoIP (PECL) for Piwik on Ubuntu 13

Tags: geoip, matomo

How do I install GeoIP (PECL) on Ubuntu 13. I have tried "apt-get install php-geoip" but it can't find the package.

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu, it's a simple PHP library.

Make sure you have libgeoip-dev and php5-dev aswell.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-geoip php5-dev libgeoip-dev
```

Also, for piwik you will want to copy the dat files into your piwik /misc folder and chmod them (ie 664 if owner is user:www-data) so the webserver has write access.